# A Cryptarithm Problem from Gelfand's "Algebra"

Tags: arithmetic

The following problem is from the very beginning of the book and it even has a solution with explanation. However, I keep banging my head against the wall unable to understand the reasoning behind it. I would be grateful if you could explain  his reasoning in a very detailed way since I cannot understand the reasoning behind every of his assumptions.

I have uploaded the problem here http://tinypic.com/r/o018id/6.

Comment: What part of the solution are you having trouble with?

Comment: The problem is the cryptarithm $AAA+BBB=AAAC$. He says $A$ has to be $1$ because when you add two 3-digit numbers and get a 4-digit number that 4-digit number must be less than $2000$ --- do you understand that part?

Comment: Why no other digit than 1 can  appear as a  carry  in  the  thousands  position  of  the  result? As well as, the following statements.

Comment: Thank you, Gerry. That was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you add two numbers, the most you can carry is $1$.  This is because the maximum of each is $9$ (and here we know they are different, so one is no more than $8$) plus you might carry $1$ in from the place to the right.  $9+9+1=19 \lt 20$